# AppCenter Updates

Tags: updates

Is there a way to configure the AppCenter to check for updates at an interval of my choosing? Also, is there a way to configure it to notify me that updates are available without first downloading them?

Answer (score 0):

At least on Odin 6 beta, updates not installed without permission. I don't think you can schedule updates too.